# How to debug using gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

I am trying to add a breakpoint in my program using

```
b {line number}
```

but I am always getting an error that says:

```
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
```

What should I do?

Comment: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html here is a good gdb command sheet. You will find everything everything you need to know about gdb.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is a quick start tutorial for gdb:

```
/* test.c  */
/* Sample program to debug.  */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
  if (argc != 3)
    return 1;
  int a = atoi (argv[1]);
  int b = atoi (argv[2]);
  int c = a + b;
  printf ("%d\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile with the [`-g3` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html). `g3` includes extra information, such as all the macro definitions present in the program.

```
gcc -g3 -o test test.c
```

Load the executable, which now contain the debugging symbols, into gdb:

```
gdb --annotate=3 test.exe
```

Now you should find yourself at the gdb prompt. There you can issue commands to gdb.
Say you like to place a breakpoint at line 11 and step through the execution, printing the values of the local variables - the following commands sequences will help you do this:

```
(gdb) break test.c:11
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401329: file test.c, line 11.
(gdb) set args 10 20
(gdb) run
Starting program: c:\Documents and Settings\VMathew\Desktop/test.exe 10 20
[New thread 3824.0x8e8]

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x3d5a90) at test.c:11
(gdb) n
(gdb) print a
$1 = 10
(gdb) n
(gdb) print b
$2 = 20
(gdb) n
(gdb) print c
$3 = 30
(gdb) c
Continuing.
30

Program exited normally.
(gdb)
```

In short, the following commands are all you need to get started using gdb:

```
break file:lineno - sets a breakpoint in the file at lineno.
set args - sets the command line arguments.
run - executes the debugged program with the given command line arguments.
next (n) and step (s) - step program and step program until it 
                        reaches a different source line, respectively. 
print - prints a local variable
bt -  print backtrace of all stack frames
c - continue execution.
```

Type help at the (gdb) prompt to get a list and description of all valid commands.

Answer (score 6):

Start gdb with the executable as a parameter, so that it knows which program you want to debug:

```
gdb ./myprogram
```

Then you should be able to set breakpoints. For example:

```
b myfile.cpp:25
b some_function
```

Comment: and don't forget to compile with debugging information (gcc has the "-g" parameter).

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you used the -g option when compiling.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell gdb the name of your executable file, either when you run gdb or using the file command:

```
$ gdb a.out
```

or

```
(gdb) file a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use -g or -ggdb option at  compile time of your program.

E.g., `gcc -ggdb file_name.c ; gdb ./a.out`