# Why am I getting a Segmentation Fault here?

Tags: c, unix, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct pr_struct{
    int owner;
    int burst_time;
    struct pr_struct *next_prcmd;
} prcmd_t;

static prcmd_t *pr_head = NULL;
static prcmd_t *pr_tail = NULL;
static int pending_request = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t prmutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


int add_queue(prcmd_t *node)
{       
    pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);
    //code
    prcmd_t *curNode = pr_head;
    if(pr_head == NULL) { pr_head = node; return;}
    while(curNode->next_prcmd)
    {
         curNode->next_prcmd = (prcmd_t*)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));   
         curNode = curNode->next_prcmd;
    }
    curNode->next_prcmd = node;

    //
    pending_request++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
    return(0);
}



int main()
{
    if (pr_head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty!\n");
    }

    prcmd_t *pr1;
    pr1->owner = 1;
    pr1->burst_time = 10;
    add_queue(pr1);
    prcmd_t *curNode = pr_head;
    while(curNode->next_prcmd)
    {
        printf("%i\n", curNode->owner);
        curNode = curNode->next_prcmd;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here's what I have now...

```
int main()
{


prcmd_t *pr1;
pr1 = (prcmd_t*)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));
pr1->owner = 1;
pr1->burst_time = 10;



if (pr_head == NULL)
{

    printf("List is empty!\n");
}

add_queue(pr1);


prcmd_t *curNode = pr_head;

printf("made it here 1\n");
while(curNode->next_prcmd)
{
    printf("in the while loop\n");

    printf("%i\n", curNode->owner);
    curNode = curNode->next_prcmd;
}
}
```

output is:
List is empty!
made it here 1

Comment: Where are you getting the segfault?

Comment: I dunno. When I run the main. Get the seg fault in the stdout.

Comment: Then run it under a debugger.  Or enable core dumps and when you get the core, run a debugger on it and see the stack trace.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm new to using unix.

Comment: segfault is generally an attempt to access memory that the CPU cannot physically address

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588853/the-community-driven-gdb-primer for some very useful GDB details

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb for some very basic starting tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pr1` is an uninitialized pointer to `prcmd_t struct`, dereferencing uninitialized pointer causes [undefined behavior](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior).

You need to allocate space for the structure on the heap / stack (depending on where it's gonna be used), so one option is:

```
// Allocate on stack
prcmd_t pr1;
pr1.owner = 1;
pr1.burst_time = 10;
add_queue(&pr1);
```

and second is:

```
//Allocae on heap
prcmd_t *pr1;
pr = (prcmd_t*)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));
pr1->owner = 1;
pr1->burst_time = 10;
add_queue(pr1);
```

Modifying your main method (and main only) to:

```
int main()
{
    if (pr_head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty!\n");
    }

    prcmd_t *pr1;   
    pr1 = (prcmd_t*)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));
    pr1->owner = 1;
    pr1->burst_time = 10;
    add_queue(pr1);
    prcmd_t *curNode = pr_head;
    while(curNode && curNode->owner)
    {
        printf("%i\n", curNode->owner);
        curNode = curNode->next_prcmd;
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
List is empty!
1
```

Comment: So you have another place with the same problem. look at the add_queue function as well.

Comment: I think you mixed the two options I gave you. Since `add_queue` expects to a pointer to `prcmd_t` (`prcmd_t *`), if you declare `pr1` as `prcmd_t`, then you need to pass its pointer `(&pr1)` to `add_queue`, but if you declare it as `prcmd_t *` then it is already a pointer to `prcmd_t` and you don't need to pass its pointer, but itself (`pr`) to add_queue.

Comment: list is still not printing    int main()
{
 
 
 prcmd_t *pr1;
 pr1 = (prcmd_t*)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));
 pr1->owner = 1;
 pr1->burst_time = 10;

 
 add_queue(pr1);

 if (pr_head == NULL)
 {
 
  printf("List is empty!\n");
 }

 prcmd_t *curNode = pr_head;
 
 printf("made it here 1\n");
 while(curNode->next_prcmd)
 {
  printf("in the while loop\n");

  printf("%i\n", curNode->owner);
  curNode = curNode->next_prcmd;
 }
}

Comment: Again, you declared `pr1` as struct, but than malloc to it for no reason and treat it like a pointer all along.

Comment: @Pulseczar - by editing your answer, but please add it at the bottom, and mention that it's an edit

Comment: I'm so confused. I thought I needed to allocate it. When I comment out that line, seg fault comes back.

Comment: @MByD I made an edit. Is there an easy way to format code or add the 4 spaces in front? Very annoying to have to manually add 4 space to each line.

Comment: @Pulseczar, first, see my edited answer, second - yes, mark the code that you want to format and press `ctrl+k` or click the brackets in the editing bar.

Comment: @MByD Thanks so much. You got me on the right track now. I'll sure I'll be back for more but thank you so much.

Comment: @Pulseczar - no problem, if this answer satisfied you, please mark it as accepted by checking the tick to the left of it.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without you tellung us where...

But

- you have to initialize
  node->next_prcmd to null
- why do you    malloc in the while loop? you are
  thereby destroing your current->next,
  which in the next iteration is pretty
  bad...

Mario

Comment: Where should I malloc? Do i need to.?

Comment: Ok,yes. I see that now. Now to fix it... The output is only "List is empty"