# sort the elements of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I want to sort members of an array `a[]` with size `s`. I have firstly used a function to get the elements, and then another function to sort them in ascending order. The problem is in the sort function or in main or in both of them, because the execution of the program ends just after entering the data. Is there anyone here that can help me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getdata() {
    int s;
    cin >> s;
    int a[s];

    for (int i=0; i<s; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
}

void sort(int a[], int s) {
    for (int i=0; i<s-1; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; i<s; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[j]) swap(a[i], a[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    int a[100],s;
    getdata();
    sort(a, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not without seeing your code.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some code to get specific help, otherwise people can only guess what is wrong.

Comment: @rt2000 you could have at least outputted the value of `s` that you're sending to `sort`.  You will see that `s` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have a local definition of the array in your `getdata()` function:

```
void getdata() {
    int s;
    cin >> s;
    int a[s]; // <<<
```

It stays local there and has nothing to do with the array you declared in main:

```
int main () {
    int a[100],s; // <<<
```

You have to write your function such it takes these as parameters:

```
void getdata(int* a, int& s) {

    cin >> s;
    for (int i=0; i<s; i++) { // ...
```

and in main call

```
int main () {
    int a[100],s;
    getdata(a,s);
    sort(a, s);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The condition in the inner for loop of your `sort()` function also looks pretty wrong, you probably meant `j` there not `i`:

```
for (int j=i+1; i<s; i++) {
             // ^    ^
```

Comment: it still stops  after entering the data.

Comment: @rt2000 It fails after you enter the data?

Comment: @rt2000 There may be more flaws with your code. I'll leave it to you to find these. I would recommend using a debugger, or at least printing out some values for testing purpose.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ῥεῖ, please could you suggest me any website,where I can understand more from this kind of topics? I don't know how to really interpret the debugging results.

Comment: @rt2000 _'I don't know how to really interpret the debugging results.'_ I don't understand this question? Just step through your program line by line, set breakpoints where you want to stop and check the current variable values when excecution is suspended. I you don't feel able to do this, just print out variables and marker messages at the points of interest for you. (to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb)

Answer (score 0):

Always use `std::vector` if you have no definite advantage by using an array (and, in C++11, use `std::array` if s is known by compile time).

```
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

std::vector<int> a;
//fill it, then
std::sort(a.begin(),a.end());
```

Comment: That's a good advice (for a comment), but doesn't answer the question!

Comment: I got it. Thanks for pointing this out.