# Write a program in C that outputs the smallest natural number greater or equal to n whose all digits are even

Tags: c, math, radix

Write a program in C that will take a natural number n and output the smallest natural number greater or equal to `n` whose all digits are even in decimal. For example, if `n = 16`, it should output `20`, and if `n = 41`, it should output `42`. 
What I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int n, i, condition = 0;

  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i = n; i >= n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      i = i / 10;
      while (i > 0) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          i = i / 10;
          condition = 1;
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
    } else {
      condition = 0;
    }
    if (condition == 1) {
      printf("%d", i);
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code to see what it is doing line by line.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: You can read the little [tuto](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2069444/7076153). It would be a start.

Comment: Well, first step would be to learn to use a debugger. How? Same way you would learn many other things. You do basic research - an internet search is the obvious first step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the i after making it 0 i.e dividing it by 10 until first digit comes. So, it'll print 0 in every case.

Instead you should try assigning the value of i to another variable so you don't have to change i. Also after it becomes 0 by first iteration it won't make other iterations due to the requirement i>=n in the for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
for (int i = n; i >= n; i++){
    int num = i;
    int cond = 0;
    while(num>0){
        int dig = num%10;
        if(dig%2 != 0){
        cond = 1;
        break;
        }
    num/=10;
    }
    if (cond ==0){
        printf("%d",i);
        break;
    }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain so that I can make this answer more useful

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I still don't understand what's wrong with my code, what do you mean by "you're checking whether 41/10 %2 == 0 or not which is true even though your condition is not satisfied."  What condition?

Comment: You're checking whether 4 is even or not in 41 but according to your question every digit should be even

Comment: for n=41 if(i%2==0) is not true so that sets my condition to zero, isn't that right?

Comment: I down vote too early, my bad. But your answer is very ugly. You don't format your code, `i` could be declare in the `for` loop. Your algorithm is very slow.

Comment: @Stargateur apart from asking him to format his code, your complaints are harsh. There is nothing wrong with declaring `i` outside the `for` loop. Furthermore, the OP has demonstrated a brute force approach to this problem, so there is nothing wrong with giving him a brute force answer to help him solve his problem.

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely My bad now i see the problem you printed i after dividing it by 10 until it becomes 0. So, now it'll print 0 every time. Instead you should've transferred the value of i to some other variable so you could've changed it's value

Comment: @RoadRunner If you think there is no problem to declare `i` outside the `for` loop, I believe that you see no problem to declare all variables in the global scope? Why do you think that this feature exist? I agree that the OP ask the problem with a brute force method. But I will be nice to see a better solution to this problem. By the way, I remove my down vote very quickly. So I don't consider the answer wrong but it can be improved in many ways.

Comment: @Now_now_Draco_play_nicely Check out my answer below, I used a different approach for this.

Comment: @Sanjay-sopho, since `n` must be a natural number, it is probably good to also check if `n > 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Sanjay-sopho answer, You can try two approaches:

- Iterative, brute force.
- recursion.

This is what the iterative version looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int check_even(int n);

int
main(void) {
    int i, n;

    printf("Enter n: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 1) {
        printf("Invalid entry, must be a natural number!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = n; i >= n; i++) {
        if (check_even(i)) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int
check_even(int n) {
    int i;

    for (i = n; i > 0; i /= 10) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Or you can try this recursive function:

```
int
check_even_rec(int n) {

    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n % 2 != 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    return check_even_rec(n /= 10); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions published so far search all numbers greater than or equal to n until they find one with all-even digits. This is terribly inefficient.

A much better method is to scan the digits once from right to left and to adjust them to get the desired result directly:

```
// assume n >= 0                                                                
int next (int n)
{
    int r = 0; // result                                                        
    int c = 1; // coefficient (power of ten) of the current digit               

    // Scan digits from right to left.                                          
    while (n) {
        // current digit                                                        
        int d = n % 10;

        if (d % 2 == 0) {
            r += c * d;
        }
        else {
            // Make sure we handle the case d == 9 correctly.                   
            n++;
            d = n % 10;

            r += c * d;

            // Since we are incrementing the current digit (or a more           
            // significant one), we must set every less significant             
            // digits to zero.                                                   
            r -= r % c;
        }

        c *= 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return r;
}
```