# Troubleshooting code

Tags: c++

This program was supposed to take input of 6 and return the 6th prime and so on.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int num)
{
int factor=2;
while(factor<=num/2)
{
    if(num%factor==0)
        return false;
    factor++;
}
return true;
}

int main()
{
int num=2, count=0, whichprime;
cin>>whichprime;
while(count<whichprime)
{
    if(isPrime(num)==true)
    {
        count++;
        num++;
    }
}
cout<<num-1;
}
```

But, it doesn't work (except for the first and second prime). For the rest, the cursor just keeps blinking at the output page. Can somebody point out the mistake?

Comment: Please describe the way in which it is not working.

Comment: You are only incrementing `num` when you have found a prime number, causing the program to loop infinitely, when it reaches `num == 4`. Put `num++` outside the loop.

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger??

Comment: `factor<=num/2` -> `factor*factor<=num`

Comment: @Yunnosch what's the difference?

Comment: If num is 100, one ends at 50 the other at 10. Both yield correct result. If you have tested 100 until 10, there is no need to test 20, because the result would be 5, which already got tested.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl Don't know what that means.

Comment: @Yunnosch But is     factor*factor<=num sufficient for all numbers

Comment: @Truth-seek that explains a lot (hint: knowing how to use a debugger is a *must have* skill). Try googling it. Or just read https://www.google.dk/amp/s/ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/amp/

Comment: If you test n/sqrt(n) you can only get sqrt(n). If you test n/m for m>sqrt(n), the result of n/m must be smaller than m. Anything smaller than m was already tested without finding it to be dividing n.

Comment: I am not sure about this. But, are troubleshooting questions off-topic @ Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks a lot. The program is a lot faster changing from `factor<=num/2` to `factor*factor<=num`

Comment: @dhke True, only for factor*factor > n > (factor-1)*(factor-1) == factor*factor -2*factor + 1. But definitly true. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Yunnosch Nah, I was on the wrong track. For `factor * factor` overflow is guarded by it being smaller than `num` ;-).

Comment: Read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic number 1. With several strict conditions met, they are on topic.

Comment: @Truth-seek Is your google/duckduckgo broken?  But ok, here's a link: https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @dhke What is `factor * factor` overflow

Comment: @Truth-seek The variables only have a limited value range. If you calculate the product of two integers, the result may not fit into that value range, causing "oveflow", even if the individual factors do. For 32bit signed numbers, the problem appears at `factor = 46341`, where `factor * factor` is actually a negative value (at least on my system).

Comment: If factor*factor > MAX_INT > n > (factor-1)*(factor-1) then you get an integer overflow in your loop and (if I guess correctly) thereby an endless loop (after optimisation proposed by me). That is what @dhke was warning me about. So you need to restrict the range of inputs for n or compare factor to round(sqrt(n)).

Comment: @Truth-Seek - you *really* need to learn how to use a search engine: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working version with minimal changes:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int num)
{
int factor=2;
while(factor<=num/2)
{
    if(num%factor==0)
        return false;
    factor++;
}
return true;
}

int main()
{
int num=2, count=0, whichprime;
cin>>whichprime;
while(count<whichprime)
{
    if(isPrime(num)==true)
    {
        count++;
    }
    num++;
}
cout<<num-1;
}
```

(move **num++;** out of **if** statement)