# Different variables of same name (C language)

Tags: c, pointers

FINAL EDIT: First of all, thank you guys for your patience. In the future I'll try to bring an MCVE to any questions I ask.

The program seems to be working fine now - I may have unwittingly deleted a typo or something.

---

This question annoys me quite a bit - I didn't choose to implement it this way, but it's required and I need to resolve it.

I've got a function that's supposed to read a piece of data from a struct, like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    char extraneous_stuff[];
} MyStruct;
...
//there's also a ParentStruct that holds a MyStruct array
...
void read_data(ParentStruct *parent, int which_MyStruct, int *data) {...
```

What I need to do is use the int *data as an out-parameter to copy the int data from inside a selected MyStruct. The problem I'm having, of course, is that **both the out-parameter and the MyStruct field have exactly the same name**. I found that trying to copy directly, i.e. `*data = parent->array[which_MyStruct].data;` compiled, but the data didn't actually get copied to the out parameter.

In order to hold to specifications I'm not supposed to change the names of the parameters here. Am I doomed?

EDIT: I included the following print statements inside the function:

```
printf("%d", *data);
printf("%d", parent->array[which_MyStruct].data);
```

and, having put

```
int n = 0;
void read_data(*parent, which_MyStruct, &n)
```

I got back

```
0
0
```

as a result.

EDIT 2:

OK, this is very weird. I have this:

```
MyStruct current = parent->array[which_MyStruct];
printf("%s", current.extraneous_stuff[0]);
printf("%d", *data);
printf("%d", parent->array[which_MyStruct].data);
```

and now suddenly "parent->array[which_MyStruct].data" has the appropriate value.
Maybe this is undefined behavior, because the only change I made was to include the print statement "printf("%s", current.extraneous_stuff[0]);" and the output changed.

Comment: it compiled because it's ok to do so. the copy failed because of something else. pls provide MCVE _https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve_

Comment: There issue is something different and it not relevant to naming convention.

Comment: Yes @KanjiViroja is correct. Naming convention is ok. Try to print *data and array[].data variables locally inside the read_data to check properly assigned or not

Comment: @Rajeshkumar I was just going to edit that in, hang on one sec

Comment: show how `parent` is declared *and* initialized. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm sorry about that; the issue is that this is schoolwork, so I'm not allowed to post the actual code. It might take me a while to generate the MCVE.

Comment: There are a lot of things that depend on your declaration of `ParentStruct` and what you pass as `parent` itself. I commend you though for taking you non-post obligations seriously, but understand it does leave us guessing a bit.... (we can't see your screen from here `:)`

Comment: @Chris, as you can see your `parent->array[which_MyStruct].data` is already 0. So *data is also set to 0. If you expect some other value, you should look at the part of the code where parent is created/initialized.

Comment: For help with debugging see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb

Comment: "*there's also a ParentStruct that holds a MyStruct array*" -- that wouldn't make sense with the struct containing a flexible array member ... maybe you mean an array of pointers?

Comment: @Yunnosch thank you for the resources, I've bookmarked both.

Comment: You can't have an array of variable-length structures.

Comment: @immibis Yes, I should've written extraneous_stuff[MAX_STUFF_SIZE].