# Program keeps crashing

Tags: c, crash

I'm new to C, and pointers for that sake, so some help would be wonderful. My program has crashed multiple times when I try to run this code.
My method punkt_paa_linje returns an integer, instead of a string, because of pointers I assume. I have a very vague understanding of pointers, so an explanation would be very appreciated

```
char punkt_paa_linje(int linje_1[3], int linje_2[3], int punkt[3])
{
int i;
double t1;
double t2;
double t3;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1 ){
    double t = (punkt[i]-linje_1[i])/linje_2[i];

    if(i == 0){
        t1 = t;
    } else if (i == 1){
        t2 = t;
    } else if (i == 2){
        t3 = t;
    }
}

if(t1 == t2 && t2 == t3){
    return "true";
} else {
    return "false";
}
}
```

And when I call the function, it returns 36

```
int main()
{
int et[] = {1,2,3};
int to[] = {4,5,6};
int tre[] = {7,8,9};
printf("%d\n", punkt_paa_linje(et, to, tre));
return 0;
}
```

EDIT: The reason I didn't insert an error message is because there is none

Comment: What are the errors? That would be helpful.

Comment: `return "true";` that's not a `char`, or an `int` . compile with warnings on we'll talk later.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb

Comment: Using `==` with `double` is a sure recipe for something not to work as expected.

Comment: try `char punkt_paa_linje` --> `const char *punkt_paa_linj` and `printf("%d\n",` --> `printf("%s\n",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain your mistakes.

You are trying to return `string` literal. Which has type `const char*` and its **seqention of characters** in *static storage duration* memory, like this

```
  n  n+1 n+2 n+3 n+4      <-- Addresses
+---+---+---+---+----+
|'t'|'r'|'u'|'e'|'\0'|
+---+---+---+---+----+
```

And you are trying to return this string via `char`, which is **one byte** in memory, like this

```
  n
+---+
|'t'|
+---+
```

So you have to return `string` instead of `char`, where string is passed by pointer to first character in `C`.

```
const char * punkt_paa_linje(int linje_1[3], int linje_2[3], int punkt[3])
...
return "true";
```

---

`%d` specifier expects parameter of type `int`, while your function now returns `string`, which has specifier `%s`.

```
printf("%s\n", punkt_paa_linje(et, to, tre));
```

---

Arrays in `C` are passed as pointer, so instead of parameters `int linje_1[3]` use can simply use `int * linje_1` or `int linje_1[]` - its same, and it will accept arrays of all lengths.

---

**[Here is live demo.](https://onlinegdb.com/H1UsD5NOW)** Just click run :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `char *punkt_paa_linje(int linje_1[3], int linje_2[3], int punkt[3])` instead of `char punkt_paa_linje(int linje_1[3], int linje_2[3], int punkt[3])`.

And use `printf("%s\n", punkt_paa_linje(et, to, tre));`. Then your code will run perfectly and give output `true`.

otherwise try :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int punkt_paa_linje(int linje_1[3], int linje_2[3], int punkt[3])
{
    int i;
    double t1;
    double t2;
    double t3;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1 ){
            double t = (punkt[i]-linje_1[i])/linje_2[i];

            if(i == 0){
                    t1 = t;
            } else if (i == 1){
                    t2 = t;
            } else if (i == 2){
                    t3 = t;
            }
    }

    if(t1 == t2 && t2 == t3){
            return 1;
    }
    else {
            return 0;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int et[] = {1,2,3};
    int to[] = {4,5,6};
    int tre[] = {7,8,9};
    printf("%d\n", punkt_paa_linje(et, to, tre));
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
1
```

Comment: _"My method punkt_paa_linje returns an integer, instead of a string"_ He didnt say that he want this function to return `int` :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should call your function `char *punkt_paa_linje`, cause here it just return a char and you need a str, which is a `char *` type.

So if you really want your function to return a `char` call it `char punkt_paa_linje`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things when returning string from function in c:-
1.Never return string local variable from function since all local variable of a function will be store in stack and stack will be destroy once function return so local varaible will be invalid now.
2.If you want to retrun string function either you should use:-
    1.Heap memory.
    2.static variable.
    3.String constant literal.

In your example if you want to return string you should use char * as a return type of a function.
char * punkt_paa_linje()

In place of using %d in printf in your code use %s for printing string.
printf("%s\n", punkt_paa_linje(et, to, tre));