# How do I get this output to appear on multiple conditions of the do while loop

Tags: c++

The program is very simple. Prompt for an employee's payroll, hours worked, pay code etc.

```
// Project Name: Lab Assignment 3
// Programmer Name: Trenton Covieo
// Date Written: 9/18/2017
// Description: This program will calculate employee pay based on  paycode and hours provided by the employee
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
//  Begin main Function Definition    
    int main()    
    {
        //intialization
        char paycode;
        string employee_number;
        int hours;
        const double min_wage = 8.90;
        double pay_rate;
        double calc_pay;
        char again;
        int employee_num = 0;

        //Diplay identifcation on screen        
        cout << "Lab Assignment 3"<< endl; 
        cout << "programmed by Trenton Covieo" << endl << endl;

        //Prompts for exmployee number      
        do{
            cout << "Enter employee number: ";
            cin >> employee_number;
            // prompts for/ determines paycode and payrate

            cout <<"Enter Paycode: ";
            cin >> paycode;
            switch (paycode)
            {
                case 'M':
                pay_rate = min_wage;
                break;

                case 'O':
                pay_rate = min_wage + 1;
                break;

                case 'T':
                pay_rate = min_wage + 2; 
                break;

                case 'm':
                pay_rate = min_wage;
                break;

                case 'o':
                pay_rate = min_wage + 1;
                break;

                case 't':
                pay_rate = min_wage + 2;
                break;

                // An incorrect code was entered
                default: 
                pay_rate = 0;
                cout << "You did not enter a valid paycode!" << endl;
                break;
            }
            // Prompts for hours worked

            cout << "Enter hours worked: ";
            cin >> hours;

            //calculates pay based upon hours entered including overtime
            if (hours <=40)  
                calc_pay = pay_rate * hours;
            else if (hours > 40)
                calc_pay = (pay_rate* 40) + pay_rate * (hours-40) * 1.5;

            //outputs information entered       
            cout << "Employee#: " << employee_number << endl;
            cout << "Pay Rate $: " << fixed
                 << setprecision(2)<< pay_rate  << endl;
            cout << "Hours Worked: "
                 << fixed << setprecision(2) << hours <<  endl;
            cout << "Total Pay: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << calc_pay 
                 << endl;

            // prompt for another employeee
            cout<< "Do you want to enter another employee? (Y/N) ";
            cin >> again;
        }while (again =='Y' || again =='y') ;

        /* This is the part that I can't seem to figure out.
           I have anoter Do-While loop that says
           whenever the paycode = 'm' it will add 1 to employee_num.
           It works fine when i have one condition,
           but if i try two (both 'M' and 'm') the cout won't work. */
        do
        {    employee_num++;
        }while (paycode == 'm'|| paycode =='M') ;
        cout <<"Number of Employees Processed: " << employee_num << endl;
```

Comment: I recommend to start treating your whitespace, newline and StackOverflow readers with respect, by adopting a (any) code formatting style. Also, curlies `{}`can be your friend.

Comment: Also, a correct [mcve] of this would have contained hardly anything apart from the last four lines. And some more lines for getting your code compilable. Please read [tour], especially [ask].

Comment: You might have found the problem yourself with either of the following: Format cleanly (I noticed the answer while doing that), https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb

Comment: My apologies, I'm not sure how to use an any code formatting style.

Comment: While you write your question, there is a huge, highlighted box titled "How to format" to the right of where you are typing. Did you read that? Or anything in the help pages? I can tell that you (still) did not take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Ya that's because the `do while` loop is in infinite loop

Use an if statement instead of do while

```
if (paycode == 'm'|| paycode =='M') {
      employee_num++;
}

cout <<"Number of Employees Processed: " << employee_num << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the endless loop caused by the fact that you do not change `paycode` within the second loop. It will continue for ever, once it has detected `'m'` or `'M'`.

Simply chaning the:

```
   do
    {    employee_num++;
    }while (paycode == 'm'|| paycode =='M') ;
```

to

```
    if (paycode == 'm'|| paycode =='M') 
    {    employee_num++;
    }
```

will fix that immediate problem.

However, I get the impression that you intend to count the employees with paycode 'mM'. That can be achieved more elegantly by doing the counting inside the previous loop.

```
    do{
        /* ... */
        switch (paycode)
        {
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                employee_num++;
                pay_rate = min_wage;
                break;

        /* ... combining O&o, T&t */
            default:
                /* ... */
        }

        // prompt for another employeee
        cout<< "Do you want to enter another employee? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> again;
    } while (again =='Y' || again =='y');

    cout <<"Number of Employees Processed: " << employee_num << endl;

    /* ... */
```

Or, if you want to count ALL employees,
as indicated by the naming of the variable and the output after the loop,
do it unconditionally inside the first loop.

```
    do{
        /* ... */
        switch (paycode)
        {
                /* ... */
        }
        employee_num++;

        // prompt for another employeee
        cout<< "Do you want to enter another employee? (Y/N) ";
        cin >> again;
    } while (again =='Y' || again =='y');

    cout <<"Number of Employees Processed: " << employee_num << endl;

    /* ... */
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Thanks!