# Compresses each row of array

Tags: c, arrays, compression

I have a function compress2d() that takes as input a 2-dimensional array (10x10) of binary data, compresses each row of the array by replacing each run of 0s or 1s with a single 0 or 1 and the number of times it occurs, and prints on each line the result of compression. For example, the row with data 0011100011 may be compressed into 02130312.

eg:

input:

```
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Desired Output:

```
1 5 0 5  
0 5 1 5  
1 5 0 5  
0 5 1 5  
1 5 0 5  
0 5 1 5  
1 5 0 5  
0 5 1 5  
1 5 0 5  
0 5 1 5
```

But i am getting:

```
1 5
1 4
1 4
1 4
.
.
.
.
1 4
```

Here is my code:

```
  void compress2D(int data[SIZE][SIZE])
  {

    int i,j=0, target, count=1, location=1;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            if (data[i][j] == data[i][j+1] && (j+1) < 10)
                count++;
            else {
                data[i][location] = count;
                data[i][location+1] = data[i][j+1];
                count = 1;
                location +=2;
            }
        }

        data[i][location] = '\0';
        location = 1;
        count = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE;i++) {
        for (j = 0; data[i][j] != '\0'; j++) {
            printf("%d ", data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb

Comment: How would you compress `1010101010`? By your logic, you would have actually expanded this to something like: `11011101110111011101` (<-the sequence may not be perfect but you get the idea)

Comment: You're accessing outside the array when you use `data[i][j+1]` and `j == SIZE-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'\0`' is the same as `0`. You never see the `0` values in your compressed array because the printing loop stops when `data[i][j] == '\0'`, which is the same as `data[i][j] == 0`. You need to use a value that can't possibly exist in the compressed data to signal the end of a row. You could use `SIZE+1`, since the largest possible run is `SIZE` copies of the same value.

So change:

```
data[i][location] = '\0';
```

to:

```
data[i][location] = SIZE+1;
```

and change:

```
for (j = 0; data[i][j] != '\0'; j++)
```

to:

```
for (j = 0; data[i][j] != SIZE+1; j++)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it to me. Much clearer now. does it means that i have to declare variable num? @barmar

Comment: Sorry, meant `SIZE` (I must have been thinking of a different question)