# Simple array initialization-population works in Linux (CentOS), but not in Windows

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, codeblocks

I have a simple initialization-population routine in C, that works fine in Linux. However when I try to run it in Code::Blocks, it produces a segmentation fault.

The code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double **rho, **ux, **uy;
double** allocate_double_array(int nx, int ny)
{
   int i;
   double** array=(double**) malloc( (nx * sizeof(double*)) + (nx*ny * sizeof(double**)) );

   if (array==NULL) printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");

   for(i=0; i<nx; ++i)
   {
       array[i] = (double*)(array + nx) + i * ny;
   }
   return array;
}

int main()
{
    int nx = 100;
    int ny = 100;
    int x,y;

    rho   = allocate_double_array(nx,ny);
    ux    = allocate_double_array(nx,ny);
    uy    = allocate_double_array(nx,ny);

    printf("Memory allocated_alter\n");
    for (x=0; x<nx; x++)
    {
        for (y=0; y<ny; y++)
        {
            rho[x][y] = 1.0;
            ux[x][y] = 2.0;
            uy[x][y] = 3.0;
        }
    }
    printf("Initialization Complete\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Any idea where it's going wrong?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of malloc() and family in C..](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb might be helpful read.

Comment: Why this cast: `...  = (double*)(array + nx) + i * ny;`? Any other reason but to silence the compiler warning you , that there is something going on?

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I am by no means an accomplished programmer, thus the style/efficiency errors. Do you think any of the suggestions might be the reason for the SIGSEGV? Especially given that it runs fine in a different OS.

Comment: The size of the malloc'ed memory is calculated incorrectly:  `+ (nx*ny * sizeof(double**))` should be `+  (nx*ny * sizeof(double))`

Comment: Similar problem when you initialize the pointers: `array[i] = (double*)(array + nx) + i * ny;` The `+ i * ny` part increases the address by multiples of `double*` instead of `double`

Comment: @Gerhardh This also helped! Thank you! Can I then turn the discussion a bit and ask, why was it working correctly in Linux?

Comment: In the end I assume that it depends on the size of `double` and `double**`. This could be different on both machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the double allocation function.

Why are you using the malloc function like this?

Try

`double** array=(double**) malloc( (nx * sizeof(double*));`

and then in the loop

`array[i]=(double*)malloc( (ny * sizeof(double));`

Comment: This resolved the issue! Could you please explain why this is?

Comment: double** is a pointer to an array of pointers to an array of type double. You only have to allocate nx * sizeof(double*) because `array` points to an array of type double* of size nx.  Then for every element of `array` you have to allocate ny*sizeof(double) because every element is a pointer to an array of type double of size ny.