# why the array in c does not swap the last elements

Tags: c, arrays, swap

I don't know what is happening in this program, 
I am modifying an array of 6 elements with this function, which is supposed to swap the elements in this way:

ex `array[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6}`;

output:

```
3 2 1 6 5 4
```

But instead, I am getting:

output:

```
3 2 1 4 5 6
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong please?

the function:

---

```
void invert (int *buf){
int i,j,swap; 

for (i = 0 ; i < ( 3 - 1 ); i++)
  {
    for (j = 0 ; j < 3 - i - 1; j++)
    {
        swap       = buf[j];
        buf[j]   = buf[j+1];
        buf[j+1] = swap;
    }
  }

for (i =3  ; i < (6 - 1); i++)
  {
    for (j = 3 ; j < 6 - i - 1; j++)
    {
        swap     = buf[j];
        buf[j]   = buf[j+1];
        buf[j+1] = swap;
    }
  }
}
```

---

I called in the main like this:

```
main ( int argc , char * argv [])
{
int k;
int array[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
invert(array);
for(k=0;k<6;k++)
    {
        printf("%d ",array[k]);
    }
printf("\n");
}
```

I apreciate your help

Comment: The debugger will tell you the answer.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb

Comment: I am compiling with "gcc -o program program.c -lm" and there is no error neither warnings, could you write how the code should looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fix

The last for loop is out of order. When you assign `int i = 3` the second for loop inside will never run as `3 < 6-3-1` is false. Copy the outer loop from above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    for (j = 3 ; j < 6 - i - 1; j++)
    {
        swap     = buf[j];
        buf[j]   = buf[j+1];
        buf[j+1] = swap;
    }
}
```

This will produce 3 2 1 6 5 4.

## Proposal:

I might add: you could implement the method in a better way even.

```
void invert (int *buf, int len){
    for(int i = 0; i < len/2; i++){
        int temp = buf[i];
        buf[i] = buf[len-i-1];
        buf[len-i-1] = temp;
    }
}
```

The above inverts a buffer quite cleanly. It's called so:

```
int main(){
    int k;
    int a[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    invert(a,3);
    invert(a+3, 3);
    for(k=0;k<6;k++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[k]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Don't always settle for the first thing that comes to mind ;)

Comment: No problem! @chang