# execution mini shell using ubuntu

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu, process, execution

I´m trying to run the following code, but it doesn´t work. I just want to execute a program, when the input name of the programm is done. I don´t know where the problem really is, cauze the code seems ok. Maybe there are other important things, that I did not notice...

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
char input[255];
char path[255];
int status;
char *args[2] = {"ls", NULL};             
while(strcmp(input, "end") != 0 ){
    printf("Waiting for input:\n");
    scanf("%s",input);
    strcpy(path, "./");
    strcat(path, input);
    if(strcmp(input, "end") != 0){
        printf("execute %s\n", path);
        int ret = execv(path, args);
        if(ret == -1){
            perror("execve error");
        } 
    }
    else{
        printf("Programm-Ends\n");
    }    
};    
return 0;
```

Comment: a) Make an [mcve] b) elaborate "does not work" c) describe the result of your debugging attempts d) as a lucky charm, get the badge for taking the [tour]

Comment: Tips for debugging: a) What is the return value of scanf() b) what does that value mean d) https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ e) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb f) https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: Tips for avoiding downvotes: a) delete the question b) edit the question (see my other comments) c) when you have more info and an improved question, undelete it

Comment: Sooner or later your negative scored questions will get you in trouble (https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). Take the advice to clean them up.

Comment: You're not initializing the `input` before `strcmp`, therefore your program has undefined behaviour.

Comment: If `execv()` is successful, it never return, because it replaces the current process with that program. So your loop won't repeat. If you want the original program to keep running, you need to fork a child and use `execv()` there.

Comment: `args[0]` should usually be the name of the program. You shouldn't hard-code it to `ls`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Barmar! Thats exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The first element of `args` should be the name of the program being run. So put:

```
args[0] = path;
```

before the call to `execv()`.