# I have problems implementing a stack

Tags: c, stack

I have a question about my piece of code here: I tried to write a function, its name is `take`, the function can get only one `int` parameter and have to return back the middle number that was inserted. The function has to use in, as minimum memory as possible. I tried to use in a stack. Its my implementation. The problem is that the program doesn't return a value after the third insertion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int take (int);

typedef struct stack
{
    int num;
    struct stack *next;
}stack;

stack first;

bool isit = true;
int counter = -1;

int main()
{
    printf("%d",take(5));
    printf("%d", take(6));
    printf("%d", take(7));

    return 0;
}

int take(int value)
{
    if (isit)
    {
        isit = false;
        first.num = value;
        first.next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        static stack newone;
        newone.num = value;
        newone.next = NULL;
        stack temp = first;
        while (temp.next != NULL)
        {
            temp = *temp.next;
        }

        temp.next = &newone;

    }

    stack *temp1 = malloc(sizeof(stack));
    *temp1 = first;
    counter++;

    if (counter > 1 && counter % 2 == 0)
    {
        temp1 = temp1->next;
    }

    return (temp1->num);
}
```

Comment: The only memory allocation you have done is for a single `struct`. Perhaps you are unlucky that the second insertion seems to work. I would expect to see either a fixed size stack, or the use of `realloc`. Or is this actually a linked list?

Comment: Here is very good advice on handling problems like that. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ I would really like to see/read you explain each and every line of your code to yourself or anybody. I expect the result should have a few more lines of comment than your current code. Current count of comment lines: 0. That is too few for any code you have problems understanding/debugging.

Comment: Second good advice (actually part of the first one, but just to stress the point): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big problem in your code is that you use global variables where you don't need
them. This creates problems that don't expect, like this:

```
int take(int value)
{
    ...
        static stack newone;
        newone.num = value;
        newone.next = NULL;
        stack temp = first;
        while (temp.next != NULL)
        {
            temp = *temp.next;
        }

        temp.next = &newone;
```

The `static stack newone` is a static variable, it means it will be always the
same every time you call `take`, you are overwriting the values all the time,
specially the `next` pointer.

For this reason, avoid using global variables when you can perfectly declare
them in the `main` function and pass them to the other functions.

Also you `malloc` part doesn't make any sense. You want minimal memory footprint
but you allocate memory which is lost after `temp1 = temp1->next;`.

If you want a minimal memory footprint and not having to allocate memory with
`malloc`, then you can declare an array of fixed length and use it as a stack,
something like this:

```
typedef struct stack
{
    int stack[20];
    size_t len;
    size_t size;
} Stack;

void stack_init(Stack *stack)
{
    if(stack == NULL)
        return;

    stack->size = sizeof stack->stack / sizeof stack->stack[0];
    stack->len = 0;
}

int stack_is_empty(Stack *stack)
{
    if(stack == NULL)
        return 1;

    return stack->len == 0;
}

int stack_is_full(Stack *stack)
{
    if(stack == NULL)
        return 0;

    return stack->len == stack->size;
}

int stack_push(Stack *stack, int value)
{
    if(stack == NULL)
        return 0;

    if(stack_is_full(stack))
        return 0;

    stack->stack[stack->len++] = value;
    return 1;
}

int stack_pop(Stack *stack, int *val)
{
    if(stack == NULL)
        return 0;

    if(stack_is_empty(stack))
        return 0;

    stack->len--;
    if(val)
        *val = stack->stack[stack->len];

    return 1;
}

int take(Stack *stack, int value)
{
    if(stack == NULL)
        return 0;

    if(stack_push(stack, value) == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "stack is full, cannot push\n");

    return stack->stack[stack->len / 2];
}

int main(void)
{
    Stack stack;

    stack_init(&stack);

    printf("%d", take(5));
    printf("%d", take(6));
    printf("%d", take(7));

    return 0;
}
```