# Printing columns m through n of each line of a file

Tags: c, string, file, text, printing

I am learning C from a book, and one of the exercises is the following:

> Write a    program that    writes  columns m   through n   of  each    line    of  a   file    to  `stdout`.
>   Have    the program accept  the values  of  m   and n   from    the terminal    window.

After hours of trying, I am unable to omit the characters after `n` and then go to the next line and start searching for column number `m`. My code's output is not right either, and I've been going at this for more than two hours and don't know what is wrong or how to fix it. My test file's content is:

```
abcde
fghij
klmno
pqrst
uvwxyz
```

and the output I get is

```
bc
```

What do I do?

*I also don't really like the way I implemented the program (having two different while loops that test `(c = getc(text)) != EOF`. It all seems overly convoluted to me, but I'm unaware as to what I can do to fix it*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure correct usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./program <file> <from> <to>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *text;

    int counter = 0, lines = 0, done = 0;
    int m = atoi(argv[2]);
    int n = atoi(argv[3]);
    char c;

    // Return if file is NULL
    if ((text = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }


    // Write columns m through n of each line
    while ((c = getc(text)) != EOF)
    {
        ++counter;

        if (c == '\n')
            ++lines;

        if (counter >= m && counter <= n && done == lines)
        {
            putc(c, stdout);
            ++counter;          

            if (counter == n)
            {
                ++done;

                while ((c = getc(text)) != EOF)
                {
                    if (c != '\n')
                        continue;

                    else
                    {
                        counter = 0;
                        ++lines;
                        putc(c, stdout);    
                    }
                }
            }                   
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you use the debugger and single step through the program. When it does something surprising, look at all relevant variables.

Comment: Three helpful links: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure correct usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./program <file> <from> <to>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *text;

    int counter = 0;
    int m = atoi(argv[2]);
    int n = atoi(argv[3]);
    char c;

    // Return if file is NULL
    if ((text = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    // Write columns m through n of each line
    while ((c = getc(text)) != EOF)
    {
        ++counter;

        if (counter >= m)
        {
            putc(c, stdout);
            if (counter == n)
            {
                while ((c = getc(text)) != EOF)
                {
                    if (c == '\n')
                    {
                        counter = 0;
                        putc(c, stdout);
                        break;
                    }
                    ++counter;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    putc('\n', stdout);
    return 0;
}
```