# c Program crashing using 2d array comparing values

Tags: c, arrays

Hi im having problems with my c code it keeps crashing with no error and im not sure why. i am trying to find the value at a point inside a 2d array for example [1][1] and see what the value is there (only 1 or a 0) and then process the value depending on if its 1 or a 0 but the program keeps crashing with no error and im not sure why.please help

```
typedef struct gol{ // structure containing a square board
    int **board; // pointer to a pointer
    size_t size; //size_t = unnasigned value
}gol;
```

the struct is created in main using

```
struct gol *GAME;
GAME = create_gol(30);
```

using an if menu options if option is selected it will just call
next pattern function but it crashes

```
gol* create_gol(size_t size){

    struct gol *Game_Of_Life;
    Game_Of_Life = (struct gol*)malloc(sizeof(struct gol*)); //dynamically create the struct the ptr is pointing to **IMPORTANT
    Gameboard = new int*[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        Gameboard[i] = new int[size];
        // each i-the pointer is now pointing to dynamic array (size 20) of actual int values
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {   // for each row
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) { // for each column
            Gameboard[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    Game_Of_Life->board=Gameboard;
    Game_Of_Life->size=size;

    return Game_Of_Life;
}


void next_pattern(gol* g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {   // for each row
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j) { // for each column
            int sum = neighbour_sum(g,i,j);
            if (g->board[i][j]==1){
                if (sum<2){
                    g->board[i][j]=0;
                }
                if (sum==3 || sum==2 ){
                    g->board[i][j]=1;
                }
                if (sum>3){
                    g->board[i][j]=0;
                }
            }
            if (g->board[i][j]==0 && sum==3){
                g->board[i][j]=1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

updates neighbour sum so it cant go out of bounds program still crashing

```
 int neighbour_sum(gol* g, int i, int j)
 { int sum;
 if ((g->board[(i-1+g->size)%g->size][j])==1){ // left
 sum++;
 }
 if ((g->board[(i-1+g->size)%g->size][(j-1+g->size)%g->size])==1){//left up
 sum++;
  }
  if ((g->board[i][(j-1+g->size)%g->size])==1){ //up
 sum++;
  }
  if ((g->board[(i+1)%g->size][(j+1)%g->size])==1){ //right up
  sum++;
  }
  if ((g->board[i][(j+1)%g->size])==1){ //right
  sum++;
   }
  if ((g->board[(i+1)%g->size][(j+1)]%g->size)==1){//right bottom
   sum++;
  }
  if ((g->board[i][(j+1)%g->size])==1){//bottom
  sum++;
  }
  if ((g->board[(i-1+g->size)%g->size][(j+1)%g->size])==1){// bottom left
   sum++;
  }

  return sum;
   }
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb

Comment: Please study and apply the concept of making a [mcve]. If you do that right, in 9 out of 10 cases, you will find the problem yourself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and read helpful things like [ask].

Comment: There should be even a very simple error msg, is there?

Comment: @BartekPL "keeps crashing with no error" seems to clearly contradict. You are still right though. Cranking up the compilers nit-pickiness should help. E.g. `gcc -Wall -pedantic`.

Comment: a) You need to show us how you call the function. b) you need to show us how board is defined and initialized. c) seems strange that gol has a size member that isn't used

Comment: Most probably is that you read more than array have, you exceed the array size when indexing. This is often at start with C language.

Comment: `Gameboard = new int*[size];` ?? Are you compiling as C++ code?

Comment: `Gameboard = new int*[size];` What is `Gameboard`? Did you want: `Game_Of_Life->board = malloc(size * sizeof(int*));`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {   // for each row
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j) { // for each column
        int sum = neighbour_sum(g,i,j);
```

means that you first call `neighbour_sum` with both `i` and `j` being zero.
Inside `neighbour_sum` you do:

```
if ((g->board[(i-1)][j])==1){ // left
               ^^^^
```

So  since  both `i` and `j` are zero, it is actually:

```
if ((g->board[-1][0])==1){ // left
             ^^^^
             ups
```

So you access the array out of bounds. That may cause a crash. In any case it is illegal.

The general problem seems to be that you don't handle when the point is at the edge of the board.

**edit after OP posted more code**

This is wrong

```
Game_Of_Life = (struct gol*)malloc(sizeof(struct gol*));
                                                   ^^^
```

do

```
Game_Of_Life = malloc(sizeof(struct gol));
```

Comment: from what you said i tried starting the integers in the for loop at 1 rather then 0 this resulted in it no crashing when the array was empty (only 0 values ) when the array was populated with 1s it still crashes

Comment: is there a way if it goes out of bounds of the array ie [-1][1] that i can use the value at the other end of the array [20][1]

Comment: @BenLeonforte Well you could do something like: `[(size+i-1)%size]` to make sure the index is always in the range `0...(size-1)`

Comment: @BenLeonforte Seems you are mixing C and C++ code. `new` is not C code. In C you must use `malloc`

Comment: i have made all these changes but its still crashing

Comment: @BenLeonforte Did you replace all `new` with `malloc`?

Comment: When trying to mallocc it gives error invalid conversion void* to int**

Comment: @BenLeonforte That's because you are compiling the code as C++. Use a C compiler if you want to write C code. Example `gcc -Wall program.c` (if you are using gcc)

Comment: i didnt write the malloc function properly that error is fixed however program still crashing at same point

Comment: @BenLeonforte Currently I don't know how your code looks so I can't tell where the bug is. I'll suggest that you do 1 of two things. Option 1) Post a new question with the code as it looks now. Option 2) Edit this question and add your current code **below** the original code (but don't edit the original code - leave that as it is).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the end there where a number of issues including i was looking for value outside of the array that was solved using

```
if ((g->board[(i-1+g->size)%g->size][j])==1){ // left
 sum++;
 }
```

i also was using c++ syntax instead of c syntax witch was resolved using the malloc function

```
Game_Of_Life = (struct gol*)malloc(sizeof(struct gol));
```

and the last issue causing the crashing still was the function neighbour sum was returning -2 because it wasn't initialized at 0 properly

```
int sum = 0;
```