# What is wrong in below linked list program in cpp?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm facing weird problem that the only 1st element of the list is get printed. I have writing linked list program after long time. thanks for the help. Is there something wrong with printAll function or add function in list class. I have tried printing previous elements while adding new one & it works. So, I'm not getting why only 1st element .ie. head is getting printed & head->next seems to be null.

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
public: int data;
public: Node *next;

public: Node(int data){
this->data = data;
this->next = NULL;
}
 };

class List{
 Node *head, *trav;
 public: List(){
this->head = NULL;
this->trav = NULL;
 };

 void add(int data){
 if(this->head==NULL && this->trav==NULL){

  cout<<"inside the if block"<<endl;
  this->head = new Node(data);
  this->trav = this->head->next;
}
else{
  cout <<"inside the else block"<<endl;
  this->trav = new Node(data);
  this->trav = this->trav->next;
}
  }

 void printAll(){
  this->trav = this->head;

while(this->trav!=NULL){
  cout<<this->trav->data<<endl;
  this->trav = this->trav->next;
  }
  }
    };

int main(){

 List list;

 list.add(2);
 list.add(3);
 list.add(4);
 list.add(5);
 list.printAll();

 cout<<sizeof(list);
  }
```

Comment: Did you do some debugging? Simplest way is to print everything before and after using it. Then https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb and if everyting else fails https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add()` method `else` part is not linking list properly, do some paper work.
Here is the working one, I tried to explain in comments.

```
void add(int data){
        if(this->head==NULL && this->trav==NULL){ /* for 1st node */

                cout<<"inside the if block"<<endl;
                this->head = new Node(data);
                this->trav = this->head->next;
        }
        else{

                this->new_node = new Node(data); /*new_node */
                cout <<"inside the else block"<<endl;

                this->trav = head;/*temp var to point to ast node */
                while(this->trav->next!=NULL)  {
                        this->trav = this->trav->next;
                }

                this->trav->next = this->new_node; /*adding at end */
                this->new_node->next = NULL; /*new_node next make it NULL */
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your add function doesn't link anything. Whenever you get into the `else` block `trav` is NULL and you set it equal a new node. But you never link that new node to the previous last node.

Normally `trav` would be named `tail` and point to the last element so that you can link a new element to the current last element.

Something like:

```
if(this->head==NULL && this->trav==NULL){
  cout<<"inside the if block"<<endl;
  this->head = new Node(data);
  this->trav = this->head;
}
else{
  cout <<"inside the else block"<<endl;
  this->trav->next = new Node(data);
  this->trav = this->trav->next;
}
```

**Edit**

OP commented that `trav` is **not** considered a tail pointer but just a pointer to traverse the list.

So therefore the answer is different as the code need to find the current tail using a loop.

Something like:

```
if(this->head==NULL){
  cout<<"inside the if block"<<endl;
  this->head = new Node(data);
}
else{
  cout <<"inside the else block"<<endl;
  this->trav = this->head;
  while(this->trav->next)
  {
      this->trav = this->trav->next;
  }
  this->trav->next = new Node(data);
}
```

However, notice:

If `trav` is "just" a pointer to traverse the list, there is no real purpose in making it a member of `List`. Simply use a local variable inside the functions that need to traverse the list.

Since your code adds new elements to end-of-list it's often a very good idea to have a `tail` pointer as member in `List`. Especially if the list can hold many elements and you frequently add new elements.

Your code use `this->some_member` in many places where it's not needed. Avoiding that will make your code easier to read.

Comment: In if block i'm setting trav to this->head->next; I'm using trav pointer for traversing the list. I don't want to use tail pointer.

Comment: @AkshayBarpute Well, if `trav` is **not** supposed to be a tail pointer then your code is even more wrong. Without a tail pointer, you'll need a `while` loop inside the `else`-block to find the current last element.

Comment: the trav pointer is supposed to act as tail pointer while adding elements & it is used for traversing linked list while printing.

Comment: @AkshayBarpute then why is it a class member instead of a function-scope variable?

Answer (score 0):

You never set the `next` pointer in `Node`.

Your code also has less-than-ideal indentation, uses raw pointers in places where you could use unique_ptr, doesn't initialise variables in constructors the C++ way, uses NULL instead of nullptr, and performs undefined behaviour by falling off the bottom without returning a value in a function declared to return a value (main(), specifically).

Comment: Using unique_ptr here seems to somewhat miss the point. If the point was to solve the problem using standard library, std::list would be a proper solution.

Comment: @Frax "don't just use std::list" and "don't use the standard library at all" are different restrictions; I'd expect modern C++ code to basically not use new at all.

Comment: These are different restriction, but usually the point of writing your own list is to learn the low-level C++, in which case writing your own memory management just makes sense. I wanted to add the writing it by hand may be sligthly faster, but probably it's not true if you use unique pointer (would be true with a shared pointer, but this one you shouldn't use, so...). And indeed, modern C++ seems to use `new` sporadically if ever.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `add()` method.

Replace it with this

```
void add(int data){
 if(this->head == NULL){  /*If head is null, init it and trav node*/
  cout<<"inside the if block"<<endl;
  this->head = new Node(data); /*init head*/
  this->trav = this->head; /*point to head of list*/
} else{
  cout <<"inside the else block"<<endl;
  this->trav->next = new Node(data); /* add new elem to next of trav*/
  this->trav = this->trav->next; /*move trav to next node i.e. reset */
}
}
```

Comment: FYI, before you downvote, please add a comment with reason.

Comment: Not my downvote, but: (1) we look for answers showing some reasoning behind the code. Just pasting the solution without an explanation is usually considered a low-quality answer, (2) this is the 3rd answer in the row and arms to add nothing to the previous ones.