# can someone help me to find the bug which results in Segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

**Note** : Actually the question is to print diagonal of the matrix in zigzag way
Given a 2D matrix, print all elements of the given matrix in diagonal order. For example, consider the following 5 X 4 input matrix.

```
 1     2     3     4  
 5     6     7     8  
 9    10    11    12  
13    14    15    16  
17    18    19    20
```

Diagonal printing of the above matrix is

```
1  
5   2  
9   6   3  
13  10  7   4  
17  14  11  8  
18  15  12  
19  16  
20
```

Now i'm just printing the subscripts of the array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
   int rows,cols,ind,inner,outer;
    scanf("%d %d",&rows,&cols);
   int **ptr=(int**)malloc(rows*sizeof(int*));
   for(ind=0;ind<rows;ind++)
          *(ptr+ind)=(int*)malloc(cols*sizeof(int));
for(outer=0;outer<cols;outer++){
         for(inner=0;inner<rows;inner++){
                  scanf("%d ",(*(ptr+outer)+inner));
            }
     }
inner=0,outer=0;
for(ind=1;ind<rows+cols;ind++){
     printf("%d",ind);
    while(*(*(ptr+outer)+inner)!=0)    {
            printf("%d %d",outer,inner);
               inner++;
            outer--;
            }printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also for Arrays without malloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int rows,cols,ind,inner,outer;
    scanf("%d %d",&rows,&cols);
    int arr[rows][cols];
    for(outer=0;outer<rows;outer++){
        for(inner=0;inner<cols;inner++){
            scanf("%d ",&arr[outer][inner]);
        }
    }
    inner=0,outer=0;
    for(ind=0;ind<rows;ind++){
    printf("%d",ind);
    while(arr[outer][inner]){
        //printf("%d %d",outer,inner);
        inner++;
        outer--;
        }
    printf("\n");
    outer=ind;
    inner=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indent your code. Do not cast the return value of malloc. Use array notation instead of `ptr+ind`. Use debugger.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb

Comment: Please delete as much of your code as possible without loosing the described problem. That is part of making a [mcve].

Comment: Add lots of `printf("I am here <number>.\n");` lines, to identify where the segfault occurs.

Comment: You seem to have `cols` and `rows` reversed in the data entry loop. Hence the segfault because the arrays are not contiguous.

Comment: . . . you are either accessing beyond the bounds of each data row (`rows > cols`), or using an unallocated pointer by breaking the pointers array (`cols > rows`).

Comment: And unlike a 2-D array you can't flow from one row to the next.

Comment: i m  only getting error in the below condition of while loop ,                                 while(*(*(ptr+outer)+inner)!=0)  *how to check whether there is an array element *

Comment: problem is only with the malloc use.

Comment: now also i'm  getting errors   sorry i don't know how to block this code in separate lines #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    int main(){
 int rows,cols,ind,inner,outer;
 scanf("%d %d",&rows,&cols);
 int arr[rows][cols]
 for(outer=0;outer<rows;outer++){
  for(inner=0;inner<cols;inner++){
   scanf("%d ",&arr[outer][inner]);
  }
 }
 inner=0,outer=0;
 for(ind=0;ind<rows;ind++){
 printf("%d",ind);
 while(arr[outer][inner]){
  //printf("%d %d",outer,inner);
  inner++;
  outer--;
  }
 printf("\n");
 outer=ind;
 inner=0;
 }
 return 0;
    }

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, casting of `malloc()` is not needed, read this [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) .

```
int **ptr=malloc(rows*sizeof(*ptr));
for(ind=0;ind<rows;ind++)
     *(ptr+ind)=malloc(cols*sizeof(**ptr));
```

And outer `for` loop should rotate `rows` times and inner `for` loop should rotate `cols` times as you allocate memory for `ptr[rows][cols]` not for `ptr[cols][rows]`.

Changes it like

```
for(outer=0;outer<rows;outer++){
    for(inner=0;inner<cols;inner++){ 
        scanf("%d ",(*(ptr+outer)+inner)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why you are doing `outer--` ? It cause segmentation fault. It's should be `outer++`. To check the element is NULL or not, your condition is correct.

Comment: I only used outer-- and inner++ to move the controller from the (1,0) to (0,1) .

Comment: `outer` intial value is `0`, what will be `ptr[-1][1]` ? when `outer=-1` and `inner=1`. You need to change the condition accordingly.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: I thought the condition (arr[outer][inner]) will get false when arr[-1][1] .