# Folding input lines every nth column (K&R 1-22) in C

Tags: c, arrays, text-processing, kernighan-and-ritchie

> *Write a program to "fold" long input lines into two or more shorter lines after the last non-blank character that occurs before the n-th column of input. Make sure your program does something intelligent with very long lines, and if there are no blanks or tabs before the specified column.*

The algorithm I decided to follow for this was as follows:

1. If length of input line < maxcol (the column after which one would have to fold), then print the line as it is.
2. If not, from maxcol, I check towards it's left, and it's right to find the closest non-space character, and save them as 'first' and 'last'. I then print the character array from line[0] to line[first] and then the rest of the array, from line[last] to line[len] becomes the new line array.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCOL 5

int getline1(char line[]);

int main()
{
    char line[1000];
    int len, i, j, first, last;

    len = getline1(line);

    while (len > 0) {
        if (len < MAXCOL) {
            printf("%s\n", line);
            break;
        }
        else {
            for (i = MAXCOL - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (line[i] != ' ') {
                    first = i; 
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (j = MAXCOL - 1; j <= len; j++) {
                if (line[j] != ' ') {
                    last = j; 
                    break;
                }
            }
            //printf("first %d last %d\n", first, last);
            for (i = 0; i <= first; i++) 
                putchar(line[i]);
            putchar('\n');
            for (i = 0; i < len - last; i++) {
                line[i] = line[last + i];
            }
            len -= last;
            first = last = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int getline1(char line[])
{
    int c, i = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') 
        line[i++] = c;

    if (c == '\n')
        line[i++] = '\n';

    line[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

Here are the problems:

- It does not do something intelligent with very long lines (this is fine, as I can add it as an edge case).
- It does not do anything for tabs.
- I cannot understand a part of the output.

For example, with the input:

```
asd        de             def          deffff
```

I get the output:

```
asd
de
def
defff //Expected until here
//Unexpected lines below
ff
fff
      deffff
        deffff
    deffff
```

Question 1 - Why do the unexpected lines print? How do I make my program/algorithm better?

Eventually, after spending quite some time with this question, I gave up and decided to check the [clc-wiki](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_1:Exercise_22) for solutions. Every program here did **NOT** work, save one (The others didn't work because they did not cover certain edge cases). The one that worked was the largest one, and it did not make any sense to me. It did not have any comments, and neither could I properly understand the variable names, and what they represented. But it was the **ONLY** program in the wiki that worked.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define YES 1
#define NO 0

int main(void)
{
  int TCOL = 8, ch, co[3], i, COL = 19, tabs[COL - 1];
  char bls[COL - 1], bonly = YES;

  co[0] = co[1] = co[2] = 0;

  while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
  {
      if (ch != '\t') {
          ++co[0];
          ++co[2];
      }

      else {
          co[0] = co[0] + (TCOL * (1 + (co[2] / TCOL)) - co[2]);
          i = co[2];
          co[2] = TCOL + (co[2] / TCOL) * TCOL;
      }

      if (ch != '\n' && ch != ' ' && ch != '\t')
      {
          if (co[0] >= COL) {
              putchar('\n');

              co[0] = 1;
              co[1] = 0;
          }

          else
              for (i = co[1]; co[1] > 0; --co[1])
              {
                  if (bls[i - co[1]] == ' ')
                      putchar(bls[i - co[1]]);

                  else
                      for (; tabs[i - co[1]] != 0;)

                          if (tabs[i - co[1]] > 0) {
                              putchar(' ');
                              --tabs[i - co[1]];
                          }

                          else {
                              tabs[i - co[1]] = 0;
                              putchar(bls[i - co[1]]);
                          }
              }

          putchar(ch);

          if (bonly == YES)
              bonly = NO;
      }

      else if (ch != '\n')
      {
          if (co[0] >= COL)
          {
              if (bonly == NO) {
                  putchar('\n');

                  bonly = YES;
              }

              co[0] = co[1] = 0;
          }

          else if (bonly == NO) {
              bls[co[1]] = ch;

              if (ch == '\t') {

                  if (TCOL * (1 + ((co[0] - (co[2] - i)) / TCOL)) -
                    (co[0] - (co[2] - i)) == co[2] - i)
                      tabs[co[1]] = -1;

                  else
                      tabs[co[1]] = co[2] - i;
              }

              ++co[1];
          }

          else
              co[0] = co[1] = 0;
      }

      else {
          putchar(ch);

          if (bonly == NO)
              bonly = YES;

          co[0] = co[1] = co[2] = 0;
      }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Question 2 - Can you help me make sense of this code and how it works?

It fixes all the problems with my solution, and also works by reading character to character, and therefore seems more efficient.

Comment: Seeing unwanted output like that I'd suspect missing null-termination somewhere and I only find a zero being written inside `getline1`. But to pinpoint the problem I recommend https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb and if those do not help https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for those links! Doesn't the '\0' inside getline1 count as null-termination?

Comment: That is the only one I found. I'd expect at least one per desired output line.

Comment: After printing from line[0:first], I also make line[0:len-last] = line[last:len]. Shouldn't that copy the null termination found at line[len] to every output line as well?

Comment: Did the debugging show that the mechanisms you describe work as expected? Debugging is the way to go if nobody else is willing to just tell you where the problem is. A hint to follow while debugging: Find out exactly which part of the output is caused by which part of the code and when. If more is printed by a "%s" than expected then make sure that there is a `\0`.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix my code, and I also learned how to use gdb. I have one doubt though - `gdb --annotate=3` I don't really understand this. What do annotations do in gdb? I tried reading up on it, and it didn't really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Question 1 - Why do the unexpected lines print? How do I make my program/algorithm better?*

You are getting the unexpected lines in the output because after printing the array, you are not terminating the new `line` array with null character `\0` -

Here you are copying character from starting from `last` till  `len - last`, creating a new `line` array:

```
        for (i = 0; i < len - last; i++) {
            line[i] = line[last + i];
        }
```

You have copied the characters but the null terminating character is still at its original position. Assume the input string is:

```
asd        de             def          deffff
```

So, initially the content of `line` array will be:

```
"asd        de             def          deffff\n"
                                                ^
                                                |
                                  null character is here
```

Now after printing `asd`, you are copying characters from `last` index of `line` till  `len - last` index to `line` array itself starting from `0` index. So, after copying the content of `line` array will be:

```
"de             def          deffff\n    deffff\n"
                                     |____  _____|
                                          \/
                                This is causing the unexpected output 
                            (null character is still at the previous location)
```

So, after `for` loop you should add the null character just after the last character copied, like this:

```
line [len - last] = '\0';
```

With this the content of `line` array that will be processed in the next iteration of `while` loop will be:

```
"de             def          deffff\n"
```

One more thing, in the `line` array you can see the `\n` (newline) character at the end. May you want to remove it before processing the input, you can do:

```
line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;
```

Improvements that you can do in your program:
1. One very obvious improvement that you can do is to use pointer to the input string while processing it. With the help of pointer you don't need to copy the rest of the array, apart from processed part, again to the same array till the program process the whole input. Initialize the pointer to the start of the input string and in every iteration just move the pointer to appropriate location and start processing from that location where pointer is pointing to.
2. Since you are taking the whole input first in a buffer and then processing it. You may consider `fgets()` for taking input. It will give better control over the input from user.
3. Add a check for `line` array overflow, in case of very long input. With `fgets()` you can specify the maximum number of character to be copied to `line` array from input stream.

> *Question 2 - Can you help me make sense of this code and how it works?*

The program is very simple, try to understand it at least once by yourself. Either use a debugger or take a pen and paper, dry run it once for small size input and check the output. Increase the input size and add some variations like multiple space characters and check the program code path and output. This way you can understand it very easily.

Comment: Thank you! I added the line `line [len - last] = '\0';` and things work now. Instead of adding it like that, would it be alright to change the `i < len - last` to `i <= len - last`, and that way even the '\0' is copied? Also, I haven't really been taught pointers (yet, in the book), so I don't want to use them. Learning to use the debugger has been quite useful. I'd honestly never used it before. I either used a pen and paper, or print statements. 

I haven't gotten around to using the debugger to figure out the second program. I will, and then post that as a separate answer.

Comment: @ApoorvaAnand Its up to you how you add `\0` at the end of new array. I appreciate you attitude. Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (and I think better) solution to this exercise :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCOL 10

void my_flush(char buf[]);

int main()
{
  int c, prev_char, i, j, ctr, spaceleft, first_non_space_buf;
  char buf[MAXCOL+2];

  prev_char = -1;
  i = first_non_space_buf = ctr = 0;
  spaceleft = MAXCOL;

  printf("Just keep typing once the output has been printed");

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (buf[0] == '\n') {
      i = 0;
      my_flush(buf);
    }
    //printf("Prev char = %c and Current char = %c and i = %d and fnsb = %d and spaceleft = %d and j = %d and buf = %s \n", prev_char, c, i, first_non_space_buf, spaceleft, j,  buf);
    if ((((prev_char != ' ') && (prev_char != '\t') && (prev_char != '\n')) &&
     ((c == ' ') || (c == '\t') || (c == '\n'))) ||
    (i == MAXCOL)) {
      if (i <= spaceleft) {
    printf("%s", buf);
    spaceleft -= i;
      }
      else {
    putchar('\n');
    spaceleft = MAXCOL;
    for (j = first_non_space_buf; buf[j] != '\0'; ++j) {
      putchar(buf[j]);
      ++ctr;
    }
    spaceleft -= ctr;
      }
      i = 0;
      my_flush(buf);
      buf[i++] = c;
      first_non_space_buf = j = ctr = 0;
    }
    else {
      if (((prev_char == ' ') || (prev_char == '\t') || (prev_char == '\n')) &&
      ((c != ' ') && (c != '\t') && (c != '\n'))) {
    first_non_space_buf = i;
      }
      buf[i++] = c;
      buf[i] = '\0';
    }
    prev_char = c;
  }
  printf("%s", buf);
  return 0;
}

void my_flush(char buf[])
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < MAXCOL; ++i)
    buf[i] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution, I know the thread is no longer active but my code might help someone who's facing issues to grasp the already presented code snippets.

*EDIT

### explaination

- Keep reading input unless the input contains '\n', '\t' or there've been
  atleast MAXCOl chars.
- Incase of '\t', use *expandTab* to replace with required spaces and use *printLine* if it doesn't exceed MAXCOl.
- Incase of '\n', directly use *printLine* and reset the index.
- If index is 10:

  - find the last blank using *findBlank* ad get a new index.
  - use *printLine* to print the current line.
  - get new index as 0 or index of newly copied char array using the *newIndex* function.

### code

```c
/* fold long lines after last non-blank char */

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCOL  10  /* maximum column of input */
#define TABSIZE 8   /* tab size */

char line[MAXCOL];  /* input line */

int expandTab(int index);
int findBlank(int index);
int newIndex(int index);
void printLine(int index);

void main() {
    int c, index;
    index = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        line[index] = c;    /* store current char */
        if (c == '\t')
            index = expandTab(index);
        else if (c == '\n') {
            printLine(index);   /* print current input line */
            index = 0;
        } else if (++index == MAXCOL) {
            index  = findBlank(index);
            printLine(index);
            index = newIndex(index);
        }
    }
}

/* expand tab into blanks */
int expandTab(int index) {
    line[index] = ' ';  /* tab is atleast one blank */
    for (++index; index < MAXCOL && index % TABSIZE != 0; ++index)
        line[index] = ' ';
    if (index > MAXCOL)
        return index;
    else {
        printLine(index);
        return 0;
    }
}

/* find last blank position */
int findBlank(int index) {
    while( index > 0 && line[index] != ' ')
        --index;
    if (index == 0)
        return MAXCOL;
    else
        return index - 1;
}

/* re-arrange line with new position */
int newIndex(int index) {
    int i, j;
    if (index <= 0 || index >= MAXCOL)
        return 0;
    else {
        i = 0;
        for (j = index; j < MAXCOL; ++j) {
            line[i] = line[j];
            ++i;
        }
        return i;
    }
}

/* print line until passed index */
void printLine(int index) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < index; ++i)
        putchar(line[i]);
    if (index > 0)
        putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: @EmanuelP I've made the changes!
Sorry I didn't add the explanation earlier as I'm quite new to C, and new to SO as well!