# Recursion flow in c language and how the output is printed

Tags: c, recursion

How is the value of I getting printed?

I know the recursion calls itself again and again. According to me, the function should return empty as the function is called before printing. How is the `printf` working?

```
recur(int i)
{
  if(i<0)
    return 0;
  recur(--i);
  printf("%d",i);
  recur(--i);
}

main()
{
  recur(2);
}

The output of this program is 
-1
0
1
-1
```

Can someone explain how is it working?

Comment: My best suggestion is to debug your code on paper writing also the 'call stack' (so you understand exactly what it does). A written explanatuion won't be as effectiv as facing it by yourself.

Comment: Your code is not valid C and I doubt it is the code that produced the output, there is at least missing `\n` to the printf format string, so please always post [mcve] and coherent things.

Comment: Well, you have to add a `#include <stdio.h>` and include another `return 0;` (and ignore the default to `int` warnings..)

Comment: My algorithms teacher always said not to try and "debug" the code on paper, as it can work in small examples, but big recursion examples would lead to "mental breakdown". As long as you have a stop condition, recursion condition and return, you should be able to debug it and see whereas the value is changing

Comment: The inplicit int rule has been removed from the C language some 20 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what happens, you have to understand how recursion works. Every recursive function requires a test condition to break the recursion and a recursive call. You have `if (i < 0)` as your test condition and then your have two recursive calls with `printf` between them.

**So How Does This Work?**

You can think of recursion and winding-up until the exit condition is triggered -- and then an unwinding as the recursive calls return. Let's see how this works here.

**The Recursion**

When you start with `recur(2)` in `main`, what path does the logic take to wind-up to the exit condition?

If you simplify the function and concentrate on what happens before your test condition is met, you get something similar to:

```
void recur (int i) {
    if (i < 0)
        return;
    recur (--i);
    /* comes after return */
}
```

Let's follow it through. On the first call, `i = 2` so `--1` *pre decriment* occurs making `i = 1`, `recur (1)` executes. Next call `i = 0`, `recur (0)` is called again. Finally, `i = -1`, and the first `recur(-1)` occurs, so `if (i < 0)` executes and `return` is called.

**Now What? -- The Unwinding...**

Look at the above shortened function. When you `return`, you are returning from the last call to `recur(--i)` so control is now passed to the next command after the first `recur(-1)` (shown as `/* comes after return */` above) So what are the next commands in the full function?

```
    printf("%d\n", i);
    recur (--i);
```

What was the value of `i` when this first occured? (hint: `-1`).

So `printf` is called and then what comes next? Your second `recur(--i)`. There `i = -2`, the `if (i < 0) return;` is triggered and you unwind out of the second `recur(-2)` -- there is no command that follows and that function call is now complete.

Control now unwinds to within the previous call where `i` is now `0`, the `printf` is called and the second `recur(--i)` is entered with `i = -1` which simply hits `return` again and you unwind one more level to where `i = 1` returning again from the first `recur(--i)` call, `1` is output.

The second `recur(--i)` call is entered where after decrement `i = 0` and you now recurse once more into the first where `i = -1` again triggering `return` which causes contol to pass to `printf` with the final `-1` printing.

You now recurse into the second `recur(--i)` with `i = -2` triggering `return` and completing the function call and the recursion.

So if you go back through the control of your recursive function with two recursive calls and look at each time `printf` was reached you have output `-1, 0, 1, -1`.

*Still Think Recursive Functions With Multiple Recursive Calls Are A Good Idea?*

(they are if you are an Aspirin salesman -- otherwise, they are best avoided unless they are the only reasonable option you have)

The only way to get through something like this is to either (1) make friends with your debugger and single-step through your code keeping a scratch sheet of which call was entered when, or (2) copy and paste the function down the page tracking the state of the recursive call at each level and take it step-by-step.

Always a good learning experience, but if a procedural solution is available, the logic is much more straight-forward and you avoid the function call overhead of every recursive call. Recursive functions have their place, and there are some problems to which they provide very elegant solutions. But you have to be mindful of how many times the recursion will occur as you allocate a separate function stack and space for local variables with every call -- which can lead to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `recur(2);`, then at this point

```
recur(--i);
```

`recur(1)` is called, and then when it reaches that point again, `recur(0);` is called and then at that point again, `recur(-1);` is called. The `recur(-1);` call immediately returns because `if(i<0) return 0;`.

The  `recur(0);` call, where `i` is now `-1`, then does the print, and returns (it does `recur(--i);` again, but that's `-2` at this point). Next, the `recur(1)` call (where `i` is `0` now) does its print, and the it also hits `recur(1)`, which returns.

Finally, the original `recur(2);` call (where `i` is 1) does its print and calls another `recur(0);`, which as we've seen, results in `-1` being printed. This results in the output of `-101-1`, or if you add a newline to each print, the output that you are seeing.

On a side note, I suggest writing your main function as

```
int main()
{
    recur(2);
    return 0; // return value of 0 indicates successful program execution
}
```

and change the signature of `recur(int i)` to `void recur(int i)` and its `return 0;` to just `return;`.

> according to me the function should return empty as the function is
>   called before printing. how the printf is working?

To sum it up, it's working because not all recursive calls are doing further recursive calls. They only do recursive calls under certain conditions, and if they don't do that recursive call, they finish at some point, allowing the function that called it to continue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling your function before you are printing out the value.

```
recur(int i)
{
if(i<0)
    return 0;
recur(--i);
printf("%d",i);
recur(--i);
}
```

You are calling `recur(2)` in your `main` function the first `if(i<0)` does not return 0 because `i=2`. Then your function recur is called with the value 1 `recur(1)`

The `if(i<0)` in this case does also not return 0 because `i=1` than your function `recur(0)` is called with 0.

The `if(i<0)` does still not return 0 beacuse `i=0` and your function is called with `recur(-1)`.

Then you're `if(i<0)` `returns 0` beacuse `i=-1`.

Now we start to `print()` out the values we gave the function previously.
Which was `print(-1)` because it was the last value that our function had.

Then we call recur again with `recur(-2)` and the if returns 0.

Then we `print(0)` because that was the second value we "entered" was 0.

Then we call recur with `recur(-1)` and the `if(i<0)` returns 0.

This goes on for the next values.

For future problems, I would recommend you to use a debugger. GDB debugger for example.

Here is a like to get started with gdb:
[GDB Start guid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb)

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

When the function is called with an argument X `>=` zero, you'll have these lines executed:

```
recur(X-1)
print X-1
recur(X-2)
return
```

When the function is called with an argument X `<` zero, you'll only have this line executed:

```
return
```

Now if you write the function calls with some indentation for each call level you get:

```
recur(2)
        recur(1)
                recur(0)
                        recur(-1)
                                return
                        print -1
                        recur(-2)
                                return
                        return
                print 0
                recur(-1)
                        return
                return
        print 1
        recur(0)
                recur(-1)
                        return
                print -1
                recur(-2)
                        return
                return
        return
return
```

Removing everything except the print gives:

```
                        print -1
                print 0
        print 1
                print -1
```

So the output is:

```
-1
0
1
-1
```

Answer (score 0):

**ALSO CONSIDER**

you are using the variable is as auto variable 
the value  of auto variables is limited with the panathesis so the program will print the value of i available within the paranthesis at which the control flow currnetly resides

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `recur(--i)`, please do `recur(i-1)`

With `--i` it will actually decrease `i`, and so in later `printf` it will be visible (incorrectly).

For eg. if `i` is `0` and you do `recur(--i)` , it will decrease the actual value of `i` to `-1` and then call `recur()`. And the `printf` will print `-1` later.

With `recur(i-1)`, and `i` as `0` it will be call with `-1` as argument but the actual value of `i` will not be changed.