# How to fix the segmentation fault error 11 appearing after running my code?

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to solve this question regarding moving data from a file to another in C. Running the program gives a `segmentation error 11`. I've attached a picture of the question. [Exercise 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgcuL.png)

I believe there is a problem in opening the files, I entered inside the terminal the C code script name: `code.c file1.txt file2.bin -b`. The files are included in the path.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

  size_t k;
  char read1[100] = {};
  FILE* s;
  FILE* d;
  if (argc < 4) {
    printf("NA");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (strcmp(argv[4], "-b") == 0) {
    printf("binary file output\n");
    d = fopen(argv[3], "wb");
    if (d == NULL) {
      printf("cant open d");
      exit(1);
    }
  } else {
    if (strcmp(argv[4], "-t") == 0) {
      printf("textual file output\n");
      d = fopen(argv[3], "w");
    } else {
      printf("error");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  s = fopen(argv[2], "r");
  if (s == NULL) {
    printf("cant open s");
    exit(2);
  }
  k = fread(read1,  sizeof(char),100, s);
  while (k != 0) {
    fwrite(read1,  k,1, s);
    k = fread(read1,  sizeof(char),100, s);
  }
  fwrite(read1,  k,1, s);
  fclose(s);
  fclose(d);

  return 1;
}
```

I expect to move all the data from `file 1` to `file 2`, and `file2 output` can be binary or textual depending on the user input stream. Ignored the 'hexadecimal' case.

Comment: Well, first look up what strlen() does.   man strlen, or just Google it.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy the text into the question, which is more friendly to screen readers, makes it easy to copy-and-paste and perform diffs on and takes up less space. Thanks.

Comment: Then do the same with fread(), especially note that it returns something essential that cannot be ignored.

Comment: Before you use `argv[4]` please check `argc`. And before you use `fread` please check that `fopen` returned a valid pointer. Without those checks, you are liable to get faults you can't detect. Aside: it's unwise to name the variable `read` the same as a library function.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've done so, still the same!  Regarding strlen(), I've read about it, I've replaced it with a sizeof(char), with 100 characters to read into my character array. still I'm facing the same problem, I wonder why

Comment: As hinted above, you also need to store the returned value from `fread` and use that in `fwrite`. Also, please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) The loop should be driven by the return value from `fread`. Moreover, you should reverse the 2nd and 3rd arguments to `fread` and `fwrite`: `size` and `count`.

Comment: ...For example `size_t bytes; while((bytes = fread(read, 1, sizeof read, s)) != 0) { fwrite(read, 1, bytes, d); }`

Comment: Hi thanks WeatherVane for following, I've edited the post following what you suggested, still the error is occurrin, I removed strlen and replaced it with sizeof(char),100 in the fread as well

Comment: You have tinkered with the code posted, but it's no longer the real code, because accessing `argv[4]` requires that `argc` be `5` or more. And, you haven't reversed the arguments for [`fread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fread?view=vs-2017) and [`fwrite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fwrite?view=vs-2017) as advised.

Comment: Yeah I've missed that, just fixed it, nothing is working I dont know

Comment: You have not changed the `fwrite`, and, there shouldn't be any `fwrite` *after* the loop. Please be careful. Aside: `sizeof (char)` is `1` by definition.

Comment: Agreed with @WeatherVane: I've had bad experiences naming variables or functions the same name as libc exports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to write a program that takes the name of an input file, an output file and a flag (`-b` or `-t`), so I guess you're calling your program like this:

```
program infile outfile [-b|-t]
```

Those are 3 arguments. They will be `argv[1]`, `argv[2]` and `argv[3]` respectively. You should **not** access `argv[4]`. Your program will segfault on `strcmp(argv[4], "-b")`. All your `argv[x]` should be shifted back by one. The check `if (argc < 4)` is ok though.

Another thing that can cause segmentation fault is reading from a `FILE*` that is not valid. You're not checking if `d == NULL` after the second `fopen()`. You should do that, and exit with an error in case it's `NULL`.

Other than this, other problems with your code are:

1. You should not call `fwrite` after exiting the `while` loop. You know that `k == 0` when out of the loop. It is not harmful, but it's useless and will print nothing.
2. You should reorder the arguments of `fwrite` like this: `fwrite(read1, 1, k, s)`.
3. Your last `return 1` statement makes no sense, you should return `0`, not `1`, for sucessful program execution.
4. You don't need to initialize the array with `char read1[100] = {};` since you don't use it before overwriting its content. Doing `char read[100];` is just fine.

PS: you should [learn to use GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb) to debug your programs. Problems like this one are very easy to spot using GDB by just stepping through the instructions one by one.