# How do I get my function to take user input and store it in an array?

Tags: c

1. This project is giving me so much grief...the first issue that I'm having is that my menu forces me to input twice and then stops when I pick an option...
2. I really am having a hard time getting program to take user input and store it in my array so that I can pass it to my functions to be either decrypted or encrypted.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>

   #define SIZE 500

   int getUserChoice();
   int getShift();
   void getString(char buf[]);
   void encrypt(char buf[], int shift);
   void decrypt(char buf[], int shift);

   int main()
   {
       char inputBuf[SIZE] = {0};

       while ( getUserChoice() != 4)
       {

           switch (getUserChoice())
           {
               case 1:
                   getShift();
                   break;

               case 2:
                   getString(inputBuf[SIZE]);
                   encrypt(inputBuf[SIZE], getShift());

           }

       }

       return 0;
   }

   int getUserChoice()
   {
       int userChoice = 0;

       printf("-------------------------------\n"
                    "| 1) Change Shift (default 3) |\n"
                    "| 2) Encrypt a message        |\n"
                    "| 3) Decrypt a message        |\n"
                    "| 4) Quit                     |\n"
                    "-------------------------------\n");

       printf("Option: ");
       scanf("%d", &userChoice);


       return userChoice;
   }

   int getShift()
   {
       int shift = 3;

       do
       {
           printf("Enter new shift value: ");
           scanf("\n%d", &shift);
       } while(shift < 1 || shift > 10);

       return shift;
   }

   void getString(char inputBuf[])
   {
       printf("Input: ");
       fgets(inputBuf, SIZE, stdin);
   }

   void encrypt(char inputBuf[], int shift)
   {
       int i = 0;

       for (i = 0; i < inputBuf[i] && inputBuf[i] != '\0'; i++)
       {
           inputBuf[i] = inputBuf[i] + shift;

           if (inputBuf[i] = ' ')
           {
               printf("%c", ' ');
           }
           else
           {
               printf("%c", inputBuf[i]);
           }
       }
   }

   void decrypt(char buf[], int shift)
   {

   }
   ```

Comment: Please focus on a single problem in your question and make an [mre] to demonstrate it. Including sample input, expect output and actual output.

Comment: "my menu forces me to input twice" -- the code calls `getUserChoice()` twice....

Comment: Have a look at these very helpful articles (even if they might seem cynical ) https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069367/how-to-debug-using-gdb

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

> The first issue that I'm having is that my menu forces me to input
>   twice

It is because you call `getUserChoice` twice:

First in the `while` header

Next in the `switch` header within the body of the while loop

***Solution:***

Define a variable like `int choice = getUserChoice();` outside your while loop and use this variable for the while and switch statements instead of calling the function again and again.

**Problem 2:**

> I really am having a hard time getting program to take user input and
>   store it in my array so that I can pass it to my functions to be
>   either decrypted or encrypted.

The problem lies here:

```
case 2:
```

getString(**inputBuf[SIZE]**);

encrypt(**inputBuf[SIZE]**, getShift());

This is not how you pass arrays to functions.

***Solution***:

Replace `inputBuf[SIZE]` with `inputBuf`

Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-arrays-are-passed-to-functions-in-cc/) post to learn more about how to pass arrays to functions in C.